# Error function with imported library jquery

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jQuery/book.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#book {
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  margin-top:15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var book = new book("book");

    function makeCode() {
        var elText = document.getElementById("text");

        if (!elText.value) {
            alert("Input a text");
            elText.focus();
            return;
        }

        qrcode.makeCode(elText.value);
    }
    makeCode();

    $("#text").
    on("blur", function () {
        makeCode();
    }).
    on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            makeCode();
        }
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="text" type="text" value="create a book" style="width:80%" /><br />
<div id="qrcode"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I created a basic code but makeCode() doesn't seem to be invoked. I have added imported the book.js and jquery.min.js under "Scripts/jQuery/book.js". By keying a value in the input, makeCode will be invoked.

Comment: change the the sequance of jquery files like **jquery.min.js** move up

Comment: JS at the top and missing the dom ready wrapper = will not work. Put all your javascript before `</body>` and read this https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: This most probably will be logging an error in browser's console. Please share that. From the top of my head you need to move your code inside `document.ready`, to make sure that `jquery.js` and `book.js` are loaded before your code runs.

Comment: As @Jehanzeb.Malik says, you need to wrap your jquery code in a document.ready block (i.e `$(function(){ ... your code here ... });`.  But it's not to make sure the `.js` file are loaded... it's because the `#text` control doesn't exist at the point your code is running

Comment: @freefaller wouldn't it throw an error on `var book = new book("book");` if `book.js` is not loaded yet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the DOM is ready or else elements may not be loaded into it yet.

```
$(function(){

    makeCode();

    $("#text").
    on("blur", function () {
        makeCode();
    }).
    on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            makeCode();
        }
    });

});
```

I don't know what the `book` function does internally, but if this has any DOM references then this also needs to be called after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/6oxu38gt/

Javascript belongs at the bottom of the page before `</body>` and your jQuery commands should be inside a dom ready wrapper (though not strictly required when at the bottom of the page).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#book {
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  margin-top:15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<input id="text" type="text" value="create a book" style="width:80%" /><br />
<div id="qrcode"></div>

<!-- javascript at the end, and load jquery first -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jQuery/book.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var book = new book("book");

    function makeCode() {
        var elText = document.getElementById("text");

        if (!elText.value) {
            alert("Input a text");
            elText.focus();
            return;
        }

        qrcode.makeCode(elText.value);
    }
    makeCode();

    $(function(){

        $("#text").
        on("blur", function () {
            makeCode();
        }).
        on("keydown", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                makeCode();
            }
        });

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery DOM must be ready.. Think of the document ready function as a self-executing function which fires after the page elements have loaded.

Place your javascript within **document.ready** code, as below...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //do jQuery stuff when DOM is ready
});
```

So, for your example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
           var book = new book("book");

    function makeCode() {
        var elText = document.getElementById("text");

        if (!elText.value) {
            alert("Input a text");
            elText.focus();
            return;
        }

        qrcode.makeCode(elText.value);
    }
    makeCode();

    $("#text").
    on("blur", function () {
        makeCode();
    }).
    on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            makeCode();
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help!!! 
The issues are:

1) ensure the DOM is ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //do jQuery stuff when DOM is ready
});
```

2) Changed the sequence of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jQuery/book.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The final result is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#book {
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  margin-top:15px;
}  

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jQuery/book.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var book = new Book("book");

        function makeCode() {
            var elText = document.getElementById("text");

            if (!elText.value) {
                alert("Input a text");
                elText.focus();
                return;
            }

            qrcode.makeCode(elText.value);
        }
        makeCode();

        $("#text").
    on("blur", function () {
        makeCode();
    }).
    on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            makeCode();
        }
    });
    });
</script>

</head>


<body>
<input id="text" type="text" value="create a book" style="width:80%" /><br />
<div id="qrcode"></div>
</body>
</html>
```